# Labelling the branches in branching chemical equations using chemfig

Tags: chemfig, chemistry, branching

---

The picture below shows what I intend to achieve:
[image: Chemical reaction with branching and the labels. I apologise for the quality of the image. I have an extremely old phone.]

---

The tex script that I wrote:

```
\usepackage{chemfig}
.
.
.
\schemestart[0,1.25] \chemfig{*6(-=-=(-CH\textsubscript3)-=)}\arrow{->[Alk. $KMnO_4$][$H_3$$O^+$]}A\arrow(aa--)B\arrow(@aa--)[-90]C \schemestop\par
```

---

The picture below shows the output that I am getting upon compiling the tex script: I am looking to add labels (like catalysts in a chemical equation) for the branches in A -----> B and in A -----> C

[image: This is the image I get when I compile the tex script. I am looking to add labels (like catalysts in a chemical equation) for the branches in A -----> B and in A -----> C]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please turn your code fragment into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Unrelated to the question but don't use math mode for chemical formulae. Instead use one of the packages dedicated to this, such as `mhchem` or `chemformula`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the following can serve as a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\schemestart[0,1.5] 
\chemfig{*6(-=-=(-CH_3)-=)}
\arrow{->[Alk. \ce{KMnO_4}][\ce{H_3O^+}]}
A
\arrow(aa--){->[some text][$\Delta$]}
B
\arrow(@aa--){->[*{0}right][*{0}left]}[-90]
C 
\schemestop

\end{document}
```